# Stopping Javascript From Submitting Form Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I am submitting to Parse and after I added in some client side validation, it keeps double submitting to the database.

I have already read some of the other Stack posts on this topic and have adjusted my code but it still is happening (I just started learning JS). Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  Parse.initialize("XXXX", "XXXX");

  $('#commentForm').bootstrapValidator({

    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        username: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        }
    }
  });

  $("#commentForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("Handling the submit");
    //add error handling here
    //gather the form data

    var data = {};
    data.username = $("#username").val();
    data.password = $("#password").val();
    data.passwords = $("#password").val();
    data.email = $("#email").val();
    // data.area = $("#area option:selected").val();
    // data.comments = $("#comments").val();

    var comment = new Parse.User();
    comment.save(data, {
        success:function() {
            console.log("Success");
            alert("Thanks for signing up!");
        },
        error:function(e) {
            console.dir(e);
        }
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the second `submit` function inside your form submit function, so try to remove:

```
$(this).submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So that is what I had added from reading StackOverflow to stop the submission from happening again. I took it out again and it is still double submitting.